# E_COMPILE_ERROR when enabling Magento compilation

Tags: compiler

I'm trying to enable compilation on Magento via the control panel and while compilation is enabled the main page fails to display properly and I find that index.php has repeatedly raised the following error in logs:

`E_­COMPILE_­ERROR: require_­once­(­)­: Failed opening required '­Config­File­Manager­Model.­php' ­(include_­path='/­var/­www/­vhosts/­<domain_name_redacted>/­httpdocs/­includes/­src­:.­:'­)­`

The site returns to normal immediately after disabling compilation but I'd really like to have the performance benefits. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware there was a Magento.SE - and I'm a freaking moderator! Can't keep up with these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like one of your extensions, or some custom code in your system, is incompatible with Magento's compilation mode.  The exact solution will vary depending on your PHP system.  Here's an explanation of the problem and some troubleshooting tips that should help you.

A file in your system contains a line that looks something like this

```
//the string 'ConfigFileManager-Model.php' may be 
//a constant or variable as well

require_once 'ConfigFileManager-Model.php';
```

The file `ConfigFileManager-Model.php` is not part of Magento, or [any publicly distributed package as far as I can tell](http://www.google.com/search?q=ConfigFileManager-Model.php&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

It sounds like when you're running in "non-compiled mode", Magento can find this file without issue.  That means it's somewhere in the normal Magento include paths

```
/path/to/magento/app/code/core/ConfigFileManager-Model.php    
/path/to/magento/app/code/community/ConfigFileManager-Model.php
/path/to/magento/app/code/local/ConfigFileManager-Model.php
/path/to/magento/path/to/calling/files/own/folder/ConfigFileManager-Model.php

#possibly more, depending on your system's default include path
```

However, when Magento runs in compiled mode, the `core`, `local`, and `community` code pool paths are not added as include paths.  Only the folder

```
/path/to/magento/includes/src
```

is added as an include path.  Additionally, what compilation mode does is make copies of all the class files and drops them into the `includes/src` folder.  That means the file's own original folder is no longer in the include path.  Because of this, when Magento runs the `require` code in compilation mode, it can't find the `ConfigFileManager-Model.php` file, and fails.

The best thing to do would be recode the module and/or custom code such that the functionality of `ConfigFileManager-Model.php` is incorporated into a standard Magento helper of model class.

The less good, but quicker thing would be to identify all the places `ConfigFileManager-Model.php` is `required` and change the path so it's absolute instead of relative.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This compiler issue is one of those recurrent plagues we all face on installing a new module. Will it or won't it compile?